# We would like to confirm that we get informed

Tags: verbs

please help me clarify this sentence. Is it right?

Comment: What is it exactly that you wish to confirm. You need to provide more context.

Comment: @Ronald Sole: I had some argument with my friend about this sentence. She used this sentence to confirm an announcement from her client. because my English is not good, please help...

Comment: It seems to me that you want to say one of the following: **We would like to confirm that we have been informed (of something)** or **We would like to confirm that we wish to be informed (of something)**.

Comment: She thought "get informed" = "get announcement"

Comment: No, your friend's suggestion is neither clear nor idiomatic.

Comment: okay, thank you :D

Comment: Welcome, @Leila and thanks for your first question. I'm reviewing it because the system flagged it since it's very short. As you can see from the comments, it needed more detail before it could be answered. In the future I'd suggest that you add as much detail about the context of your question and what you have done to try to answer it yourself when you post. Short questions like this will continue to be flagged and might be closed or downvoted.